# HTML/Ajax - Dynamically Displaying Data

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I'm working on creating an e-commerce site for a project, which requires reading data from a JSON file and then displaying it on screen, with the relevant information. I've been able to link the file to my HTML document and using the console, am able to list information such as the product name. My question is how would I go about putting this information onto the website and creating a new container per product?

I've created the layout for how these products should be displayed, with some dummy data included and created some CSS along with it. Could someone illustrate how I'd go about creating a new shopping-container for every product listed inside the JSON file, so every product that is inside the JSON file is produced as shown in the screenshot below?

Script  & Div Layout:

```
    <section class="section-offer js--section-offer" id="offer">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>What We Offer.</h2>
            <p class="long-copy">
            </p>
            <script>
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'products.json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'get',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $(data.products).each(function(index,value) { //Grabs every single item inside of the json file
                            console.log(value.name);
                        });
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="shopping-container">
            <div>
                <h4>Logitech G910 Orion Spectrum RGB Mechanical Gaming Keyboard - UK-Layout</h4>
                <p class="shopping-container-desc">Logitech 920-008017 G910 Orion Spectrum RGB Mechanical Gaming Keyboard - Black.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="shopping-container-img">
                <img src="images/02.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="basket.html" class="btn btn-full">&pound;199.99</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Layout of the JSON file

```
{
  "products" : [
    {
      "id" : "0",
      "name" : "Logitech G910 Orion Spectrum RGB Mechanical Gaming Keyboard - UK-Layout",
      "price" : "119.99",
      "category" : "0",
      "description" : "Logitech 920-008017 G910 Orion Spectrum RGB Mechanical Gaming Keyboard - Black.",
      "images" : [
        {
          "id" : "0",
          "src" : "images/00.jpg"
        },
        {
          "id" : "1",
          "src" : "images/01.jpg"
        },
        {
          "id" : "2",
          "src" : "images/02.jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try investigating tools such as [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html), [Angular](https://angular.io/) or [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/). All offer great functionality to do as you desire and some more. All (if memory serves) offer the concept of components, which allows the replication of some HTML but with varying data appearing within it; i.e: what you want here.

Comment: No problem. I would recommend, if you choose to take this route, to look into Knockout first. In my opinion, it's the best documented and offers great guides and examples for first time users. The syntax is also fairly sensible.